# Can ArcGIS Network Analyst solve multiple vehicle routing problem?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, routing, vehicle-routing-problem

Can network analyst tool solve multiple vehicle routing problem, or is it only solved by using ArcLogistics Route?

Answer (score 3):

Network Analyst extension for ArcGIS has a solver *Vehicle Routing Problem* (VRP). This solver does have support for multiple vehicles.

Look for the [Routes class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/vehicle-routing-problem.htm) inside the Help page.

> This network analysis class stores the routes that are part of a given
>   vehicle routing problem analysis layer. A route specifies the vehicle
>   and driver characteristics, and it represents the traversal between
>   depots and orders. In Network Analyst, vehicles, routes, and drivers
>   are synonymous, and the term route is used to encompass all three.

To get started using VRP solver, go through these two tutorials:

- [Exercise 7: Servicing a set of orders with a fleet of vehicles](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-7-servicing-a-set-of-orders-with-a-fleet-of-vehicles.htm)
- [Exercise 8: Finding best routes to service paired orders](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-8-finding-best-routes-to-service-a-set-of-paired-orders.htm)

Answer (score 1):

[ArcLogistics Route has been retired since 1 Dec 2013](http://support.esri.com/Products/more-products/legacy-products/arclogistics-route#product-support), so so it is no longer available to solve your multiple vehicle routing problem.

Consequently, I think you should follow the advice in the [answer from @AlexTereshenkov](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/241928/115).